# Writing big CSV files to GCS on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-storage

I'm extracting huge amounts of data from the Google App Engine Datastore (using Python) and I need to write it to a csv file on GCS (Google Cloud Storage).

I do this task by fetching ~10k entities with iter query and deferring the task.
Unfortunately GCS doesn't support appending to files, and because of that in each run of the task I'm forced to open and read the whole file, close it, then write the content to a new file and add the newly fetched batch of data to it.

I'm using the UnicodeWriter/UnicodeReader for handling csv files similar to:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples

My problem is that when the file gets bigger it tends to eat a lot of instances memory and sometimes exceeds the limit. Is there any way to minimize the extensive memory usage in this case?

Any examples of handling big csv files > 32MB on GCS are quite welcome.

Comment: Can you write to multiple files and then use [object composition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects) to put them together?

Comment: GCS compose (concatenation) sounds like an excellent solution, though I believe only for up to 32 chunks; an alternative might be to use GCS resumable uploads of the kind with a-priori unknown length (if you can prep things up in multiples of 256k bytes except for the very tail, which should be a bit tedious but far from unfeasible).

Comment: Have you tried to use mapreduce lib? It should handle such operations nicely. It has built-in datastore readers and blolbstore writers.

Comment: unfortunately using mapreduce won't solve my memory issues.

The object composition option looks really promising, does anybody have a working example of this? A simple POC code would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage can happily accept objects of basically unlimited size, but your problem is a little different, which is constructing the object in the first place.

You can use Google Cloud Storage's composition support to help. However, compose has limits. You can compose up to 1024 objects in total (32 objects per call, but the result of that object can be composed, as can the result of that object, and so on and so forth until there are 1024 original source objects that have been composed together). Thus, composition will only work if breaking the total size up into 1024 pieces makes them sufficiently small for your use case.

However, maybe that's good enough. If so, here are some resources:

Documentation of the compose feature: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#_Compose

I'm not sure if you're using the App Engine Cloud Storage library, but if you are, it unfortunately doesn't support compose. You'll have to grab the more generic Google API Python client and invoke the objects#compose method, documented here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose

Here's the relevant example of using it:

```
composite_object_resource = {
        'contentType': 'text/csv',  # required
        'contentLanguage': 'en',
}
compose_req_body = {
        'sourceObjects': [
                {'name': source_object_name_1},
                {'name': source_object_name_2}],
        'destination': composite_object_resource
}
req = client.objects().compose(
        destinationBucket=bucket_name,
        destinationObject=composite_object_name,
        body=compose_req_body)
resp = req.execute()
```

Comment: Great example, thanks!
Do I have to have a separate bucket for this or is it safe because only  items from 'sourceObjects' list are going to be composed?

Comment: It's safe. Only the sourceObjects are composed, and even those objects won't be removed. Keep that in mind because, once you've composed the final object, you might want to remove the original components so that you're not charged for them.

Comment: How to use that api on local gae development server?

Comment: Unfortunately, that client does not work with the GAE development server. Fortunately, since I wrote this answer last December, compose support has been added to the other client library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/commit/5fab4b41be416a6395eb6b659b7b600c3d184a3d

Answer (score -1):

When you write something [like](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python/blob/master/blob_files.py):

```
with gcs.open(gcs_filename, 'w', content_type=b'multipart/x-zip') as gf:
    ....
```

Here gf is a cloudstorage.storage_api.StreamingBuffer, which can be pickled to append data in a chained task. But I did not try this yet.